# Defining a surjective $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $p,q$ be prime numbers. I want to define a surjective $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})[X]\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q})$, where $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})=\{a+b\sqrt{d}:a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.

Given a polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}X^{i}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})[X]$, I tried sending it to $a_{0}\otimes 1$, which seems to define a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra homomorphism, but it doesn't seem to be surjective. I also tried sending it to $a_{0}\otimes\sqrt{q}$ but it doesn't work. There are somewhat natural choices for the first entry but my main problem is getting the second entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q})\simeq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})[X]/(X^2-q)$ by using the following properties of tensor product of algebras: $A\otimes_A B\simeq B$ and $A[X]\otimes_AB\simeq B[X]$, where $B$ is an $A$-algebra.

Comment: Quick comment, it looks from the first line of your answer that we have $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}) \otimes_{\Bbb{Q}} \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{q}) \cong \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})$? Do we always have this? Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaLim In Milne's [ANT Notes (pdf)](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf) on pages 24-25 he proves a variant of what YACP is referring to. As long as the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{q}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p})$, you'll have the desired isomorphism.